# Findbugs eclipse plugin is showing SE_BAD_FIELD for the instance of HashMap in my class

Tags: java, serialization, findbugs

I have a instance of `HashMap<MyClass2,Queue<Point2D>>` in my class. My class implements `JPanel`. *Findbugs* is showing **SE_BAD_FIELD** for the instance of `HashMap` in my class but `HashMap` implements `Serializable`. I am using findbugs 3.0.0X, and JDK 1.7.0_45.

> Se: Non-transient non-serializable instance field in serializable
>   class (SE_BAD_FIELD)
>
> This Serializable class defines a non-primitive instance field which
>       is neither transient, Serializable, or java.lang.Object, and does
>       not    appear to implement the Externalizable interface or the
>       readObject()    and writeObject() methods. Objects of this class
>       will not be    deserialized correctly if a non-Serializable object
>       is stored in this    field.

---

Comment: Is every field in MyClass2 serializable?  What about Point2D?

Comment: Key type and Value type of `HashMap` should be `Serializable` too?

Comment: `MyClass2` is not `Serializable`. `Point2D` is a java class from `java.awt.geom` package.

Comment: If MyClass2 is not Serializable, a HashMap with them as the Key Type won't be either, so that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a HashMap field as:

```
private Map<MyClass2,Queue<Point2D>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

FindBugs will complain because `Map` interface is not serializable, so you can put any class there that might not be serializable, if you change the type to `HashMap` (or add `transient`) you will get rid of the warning.

Comment: When I change it to `HashMap` it still shows warning because `MyClass2` is not `Serializable` as @WPrecht - AB3RY said. When I  add `transient` after creating instance of `Map`, findbugs shows **SE_TRANSIENT_FIELD_NOT_RESTORED** error.